# How do I make a pcmanfm right-click desktop entry work only for the Desktop folder?

Tags: menu, pcmanfm, lxqt

```
System:    Host: MyComputer Kernel: 4.8.14-gnu-1 x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: LXQt Distro: Parabola GNU/Linux-libre
```

I have created the following entry:

*./.local/share/file-manager/actions/monitor-settings-action.desktop*

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Action
Tooltip=Monitor Settings
Name=Monitor Settings
Profiles=profile-zero;
Icon=preferences-desktop-display

[X-Action-Profile profile-zero]
Exec=lxqt-config-monitor
Name=Default profile
Folder=/home/folatt/Desktop
```

The 'Folder' part doesn't seem to work. The menu option still shows up at every directory.

What am I doing wrong?